# Как упростить процесс разработки UI локализованных приложений C#, WinForms, VS2019

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Уважаемые коллеги, для разработки локализованных приложений MS придумала нам свойство Form.Localizable, которое, если установить его в true, даст нам возможность указать для каждого контрола на форме свое содержимое для каждой отдельной локали. Надо лишь в свойстве Language выбрать соответствующий язык. Вопрос заключается в следующем: можно ли как-то сократить список из стотыщпятьсот языков до двух-трех-четырех используемых, а то убивает каждый раз листать этот огромный список в поисках строки Русский (Ru-Ru), а контекстного поиска там нет.

Comment: `а контекстного поиска там нет` там - это где?

Comment: ответ довольно очевиден, но вам, вероятно, не понравится. Не листайте список в UI-дизайнере, а посмотрите что он генерирует на выходе и делайте все кодом, без UI-дизайнера. В конце концов макет можно сделать в UI-дизайнере и потом разможить чистым кодом.

Comment: @tym32167 - в редакторе свойства Language формы.

Comment: @rdorn - ну почему же сразу не понравится... Так и происходит, в основном. Но иногда, если есть просто десяток статичных Label - проще (быстрее) сделать в UI-дизайнере формы. imho. Зачем-то эту фичу в MS придумали ж ...

Comment: Демонстрация поиска с анимацией в ответе, а по поводу "для чего-то же придумали", придумали да, попытались сделать как в дельфи, только так и не довели до ума ни WinForms, ни дизайнер для них, и теперь уже не доведут, ибо: устарело, не модно, ни кто не пользуется - понравившееся подчеркнуть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Своеобразный контекстный поиск по языкам есть. Чтобы его использовать нужно в поле комбобокса для выбора языка просто текстом набрать код языка, вроде "ru", или "en-us", если нужно выбрать конкретный диалект.

[image: Демонстрация поиска]

В принципе, если вы знаете точный текстовый код языка, то даже раскрывать список не нужно, просто нажмите enter после ввода нужного кода.

Comment: Кстати, да. Спасибо!